# JFK vs EWR: which is better for arrival with an infant? (immigration lines etc)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, children, jfk, ewr

We'll be visiting the US with a young kid (<2 y.o.) and I wonder which of the airports will be better in terms of immigration lines (in EWR they seem to be shorter on average) and general accessibility for families with small kids.

Someone told me that airport workers in JFK usually help infants+parents skip the immigration line - is this true?

The flight is going to be from EU, likely Lufthansa.